# Sum of positive terms gives negative answer

Tags: bugs, symbolic, summation

**Bug introduced in 7.0 and fixed in 9.0**

---

Mathematica evaluates `Sum[((n - y - 1)*(n - y)^2*n^y)/y!, {y, 0, n - 2}]` as `-2 e^n n`.  This should not be a negative value.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a problem of version 8. In version 9.04 I get  `(1/(n! Gamma[
  n]))(-n! (5 n^n + E^n (1 + 4 n) Gamma[n] - E^n Gamma[n, n] - 
     2 E^n Gamma[1 + n, n]) + 
  n^n Gamma[n] HypergeometricPFQ[{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1 + n}, n])`.

Comment: OK.   HypergeometricPFQ[{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1 + n}, n] looks very hard to interpret! Do you have any idea what that looks like asymptotically?

Comment: @Sjoerd Interestingly, if you simply change the upper limit from `n-2` to `n-1` (which introduces a zero into the sum, leaving it unaltered) *MMA* 8 obtains `(1/((1 + n)! Gamma[
  2 + n]))n ((1 + n)! (n^n (1 + 2 n) - E^n Gamma[2 + n] - 
      E^n Gamma[2 + n, n]) + 
   n^n Gamma[2 + n] HypergeometricPFQ[{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2 + n}, n])`--which numerical tables show is correct.  Also, if the full `Sum` is involved within a more complex expression, it might get evaluated correctly.

Comment: Lembik, hypergeometric functions are *nice*: they have series expansions, known poles, integral representations, etc.  Take a look at the help page for the series definition.

Comment: @whuber Fact remains that this particular result is indeed dead wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently a problem of version 8 where I get the same. In version 9.0.1 I get

```
(1/(n! Gamma[ n]))(-n! (5 n^n + E^n (1 + 4 n) Gamma[n] - E^n Gamma[n, n] - 
2 E^n Gamma[1 + n, n]) + n^n Gamma[n] HypergeometricPFQ[{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1 + n}, n])
```

or, with nicer formatting,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This can be reduced with

```
Sum[((n - y - 1)*(n - y)^2*n^y)/y!, {y, 0, n - 2}] // FullSimplify
```

to

> (2 n (n^n - E^n Gamma[n, n]))/Gamma[n]

or, in `TraditionalForm`,

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's very clever of Mathematica!

Comment: WA online gives the same error. Wouldn't they be using the most recent version?

Comment: @Lembic I seem to recall reading that W|A is updated frequently, so indeed that is what one would expect.

Comment: I mean W|A gives the wrong answer where apparently 9.0.1 gives the right answer.  I don't have 9.0.1 to test sadly. On a related topic, do Wolfram release bug fixes for Mathematica or do you have to wait another year to get an upgrade?

Comment: @lembik I understood what you meant, and I find it curious as well. As to fixes: WRI releases only a few updates for each major version. Generally I'd say two or three. Depending on your license you may or may not have access to them.